# Anyone know of an ASP.NET equivalent to the Rails auto_link helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

A fast function for scanning text for urls and turning them into html hyperlinks would be very nice... I'd write one but I feel like the odds of someone already having written one are high...

Thanks!
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Autohyperlink.aspx